# Upgrade the postgresql version in docker with docker-alpine-postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

I took over a website project running in a docker environment. Recently AWS requested to update the postgresql version, in my case from 9.5 to at least 12. The compose-yaml of the docker project looks as follows:

```
  postgres:
    build: ./images/postgres
    image: project:con-postgres
    container_name: con-postgres-server
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - "DEVNET"
```

In the ./images/postgres folder the following dockerfile (and an executeSql.sh) is defined:

```
#vim: set ft=dockerfile:
# based on https://github.com/onjin/docker-alpine-postgres/
FROM onjin/alpine-postgres

EXPOSE 5432

# add helper script which executes multiple files in a given folder - used for db init and testdata fill
COPY executeSql.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

I found some tutorials on how to update psql directly in the compose-yaml, but did not find a suitable tutorial on how to update the postgresql version with my setting, where alpine-postgres seems to define the postgres-version.

My question is, how to update the postgresql version with `onjin/alpine-postgres`? Of course, I would strongly appreciate hints to any helpful tutorial.

Comment: You don't normally "upgrade" software in an image; you generally start from scratch building a new image with the version you want.  The GitHub repository you link to hasn't seen an update in over a year, and notes the [official Docker Hub `postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) has Alpine-based images; can you use `postgres:12` (or `postgres:12-alpine` if you have reason to care about the base distribution) instead of this community image?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution myself. I had to simply add the version number directly to the "FROM" statement in my dockerfile. Here is the code, that was working for me:

```
#vim: set ft=dockerfile:
# based on https://github.com/onjin/docker-alpine-postgres/
FROM onjin/alpine-postgres:12.4    
EXPOSE 5432

# add helper script which executes multiple files in a given folder - used for db init and testdata fill
COPY executeSql.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

As stated by @David Maze, it might be better to switch to "postgres:12" or "postgres:12-alpine", since the onjin/alpine-postgres GitHub project hasn't seen an update in over a year.